# Function hint - possible values for parameters

Tags: php, function, phpstorm, laravel-8, type-hinting

Is it possible to show a user of PhpStorm what the possible function arguments are, not just the type of argument?

For example, I have a function that will show the programmer that two strings are needed, as shown in this graphic:

[image]

However, I would like the hint to show the possible values for each variable  - `tag` and `tag_type` in this example; e.g.,

- The possible values for tag are "full, view, edit, add, or delete".
- The possible values for variable tag_type is a list of about 10 or so activities in the database.

Here is the code I have.  Can it be changed to show the user in PhpStorm what the allowed variable values are?

```php
/**
 * @param string $tag
 * @param string $tag_type
 * @return int
 *
 * [tag] = full, view, edit, add, or delete
 * [type] = all, activities, grades, orders, people, schools, users, team_classes,
 *          coaches, team_parents, or organization
 *
 * by default, if leave arguments blank, you are asking if the current user is a full admin,
 */
public function isAdmin(string $tag = '', string $tag_type = ''){

    if ($this->isFullAdmin())
        return true;

    return $this->tagas()
        ->where('tag', '=', 'full')
        ->where('tag_type', '=', $tag_type)
        ->orWhere(function($query) use ($tag, $tag_type) {
            $query->where('tag','=',$tag)
                  ->where('tag_type','=', $tag_type);
        })->count();
}
```

---

Okay, I came up with this, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I checked my php version with phpversion() and it is 8.0.2.

```
    public function isAdmin(
        #[ExpectedValues(['all', 'activities', 'grades', 'orders', 'people', 'schools', 'users',
            'team_classes','coaches', 'team_parents', 'organization'])] string $tag_type = '',
        #[ExpectedValues(['*', 'full', 'view', 'edit', 'add', 'delete'])] string $tag = '*'
    ){
```

Yet it has only changed the type hinting slightly.
[image]

It shows [ExpectedValues] but doesn't show the actual expected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **PhpStorm Advanced Metadata**. In particular: *Arguments Accepted by a Method* functionality -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#expected-arguments.

Make a separate PHP-alike file named `.phpstorm.meta.php` and place it in the project root. PhpStorm will parse and use the data from this file in appropriate places. Works with any modern PHP version; it is used by Laravel IDE Helper as well as by Symfony plugin to name a few.

```php
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    expectedArguments(\AUser::isAdmin(), 0, 'full', 'view', 'edit', 'add', 'delete');
}
```

[image]

---

**For PHP 8** you can use custom `#[ExpectedValues]` **PHP attribute made by JetBrains**:

- https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes#expectedvalues
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-release/#expectedvalues

This way all values are stored together with the method itself and not a separate file.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ExpectedValues;

class AUser {
    /**
     * Bla-bla ...
     * 
     * By default, if leave arguments blank, you are asking if the current user is a full admin.
     * 
     * @param string $tag
     * @param string $tag_type
     * @return int
     * 
     */
    public function isAdmin(
        string $tag = '',
        #[ExpectedValues(['all', 'activities', 'grades', 'orders', 'people', 'schools', 'users', 'team_classes', 'coaches', 'team_parents', 'organization'])]
        string $tag_type = ''
    )
    {
        if ($this->isFullAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }

        return $this->tagas()
            ->where('tag', '=', 'full')
            ->where('tag_type', '=', $tag_type)
            ->orWhere(function($query) use ($tag, $tag_type) {
                $query->where('tag','=',$tag)
                      ->where('tag_type','=', $tag_type);
            })->count();
    }
}

$user = new AUser();
$user->isAdmin('full', '');
```

[image]

The IDE can also hint you that an unexpected value is used:
[image]

NOTE: it's a Weak Warning severity so it's not super visible (you may adjust that in the inspection settings):
[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!  I notice that I have to 

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ExpectedValues;

which i did not do.  Thank you!  what a great feature now that it is inline.
---
actually, phpStorm put the use ref in for me automatically.  What I did wrong was putting a comma after the [ExpectedValues] statement.  

Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: It this can be used in VS Code?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed No clue. I'm not using VSCode and do not if there is any extension that would support these kind of attributes.

Comment: @LazyOne it doesn't work on VS Code, I tried it.

Comment: @JenuelGanawed It is also possible to use psalm PHPDoc attributes to list acceptable values for the parameter. At very list it is used by **psalm** for static code analysis. In PhpStorm they can also be used for code completion (never used them myself, so cannot comment how well it works but it should). Perhaps there is a plugin for VSCode that can use that?